# Robbed on Halloween!

Tags: riddle, word

Here's a riley:

```
My prefix is where rainbows are
My infix is what maps show
My suffix is a person
And my whole can rob you
```

Comment: Congrats on 1000 rep @Duck!

Comment: Thanks! I was going to make a celebration riddle.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Second attempt:

> highwayman.

My prefix is where rainbows are

> Up HIGH, still.

My infix is what maps show

> Maps show you the WAY. (Please no meme references)

My suffix is a person

> A MAN is indeed a person.

And my whole can rob you

> TIL that a HIGHWAYMAN is "a man, typically on horseback, who held up travelers at gunpoint in order to rob them".

<s>A guess:</s>

> Hijack.

My prefix is where rainbows are

> Rainbows are up HI in the sky.

My infix is what maps show

> Not sure on this one.

My suffix is a person

> Jack can be a person's name.

And my whole can rob you

> Hijacking is similar to robbing.

Comment: Sorry, but nope. Hi is right and wrong if you know what I mean

Comment: @Duck Updated :)

Comment: One of my favourites, [with sword and pistol by my side](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFkcAH-m9W0)

Comment: That is correct!